# How to use placeholders with "in (...)" clause?

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi

I know I can do this with interpolation.  Can I do it using placeholders?

I am getting this error:

```
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "{"22,23"}" at ./testPlaceHolders-SO.pl line 20.
```

For this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use DBI;

# Connect to database.

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=somedb;host=localhost;port=5432", "somedb", "somedb");

my $typeStr = "22,23";
my @sqlParms = [ $typeStr ];
my $sqlStr = << "__SQL_END";
    SELECT id
    FROM states
    WHERE typeId in (?)
    ORDER BY id;
__SQL_END

my $query = $dbh->prepare($sqlStr);
$query->execute(@sqlParms);

my $id;
$query->bind_columns(\$id);

# Process rows

while ($query->fetch())
{
    print "Id: $id\n";
}
```

Is there a way around it besides interpolation?

Comment: Why are you executing the query using an array reference? `[ $typeStr ]`?

Comment: And yes, there is a way around it. Don't use a string, use numbers. Such as `my @nums = (22,23); my $placeholder = join ",", ("?") x @nums; $query->execute(@nums);`

Comment: Your solution works.  If you want to make an official answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting comment as answer, as requested.

Generate your own placeholder string. Like so:

```
my @nums = (22,23); 
my $placeholder = join ",", ("?") x @nums; 
$query->execute(@nums);
```

Comment: when doing this, make sure @nums is never empty, since `in ()` will unfortunately be an sql syntax error.

Comment: See my answer below - there is a cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 9):

[`DBD::PG`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3aPg) has support for [PostgreSQL arrays](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3aPg#Array-support), so you can simply write a query like this:

```
WHERE typeid = ANY( ARRAY[1,2,3] )
```

or, with a parameter...

```
WHERE typeid = ANY(?)
```

Then just use the array support

```
my @targets = (1,2,3);
# ...
$query->execute(\@targets);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You must use placeholders for each value, such as `IN (?, ?, ?)`. You can however generate the correct number of question marks using something like this (untested):

```
my @values = (22, 23, ...);
# will produce "?, ?, ..."
my $in = join ", ", ("?") x @values;
my $sqlStr = "SELECT id FROM states WHERE typeId in ($in) ORDER BY id;";
my $query = $dbh->prepare($sqlStr);
$query->execute(@values);
```

Note that if you use an ORM such as [DBIx::Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBIx%3A%3AClass) instead, this sort of ugly hack gets abstracted away.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the SQL statement with the correct number of question marks and then set the parameter values.  There is no way to bind a list to a single question mark.